# 2D XNA-Camera and fixed Background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, camera

I am currently creating a XNA-Game for Windows Phone. I have a problem concerning the 2D camera and the background.

Is it possible to move the XNA-Camera and fix the background, so that it is not moving with the camera-view? Furthermore also my pause-button and the menu-bar is moving, hopefully it's possible to fix them to the top of the screen.

UPDATE:
Here is my move-Methode from the camera class:

```
    public void Move(Vector2 amount)
    {
        _pos += amount;
    }
```

Screenshot: http://www.abload.de/img/screenshotbdllj.png

As you can see on the picture the box-object is falling top-down and the background is moving up. Is there a way to keep the background static fixed?

Comment: 2D or 3D? Can you show some of the relevant camera code, or maybe a screenshot? Remember that XNA has no built-in "camera" as such - so you have to tell us what you're doing.

Comment: 2D, I just updated my Question with a Screenshot! Thanks

Comment: Not enough info. In the DrawCall you can just take the camera into account or you don't. It should be rather simple. Remember from a mathematical view, it doesn't matter if the camera moves or the object moves in the opposite direction. Just apply the camera position inverted each frame to your objects. And for the UI elements, just don't apply the camera position at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Do you have an example that shows how to not apply the camera position?

One more question is it possible to create some layers in XNA? That would be more simple i think, if it's possible to create a fixed layer, that don't move.

Answer (score 3):

If you work in 2D-Space you'll could have something like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SomeSortmode,nullnull,etc..., Matrix);
//drawstuff
spriteBatch.End();
```

If this is the case, move your rendering code into another Begin() and End()

I think of something like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SomeSortmode,nullnull,etc..., Matrix);
//draw stuff affected by the camera
spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin()
//draw stuff which should not be affected by the camera
spriteBatch.End();
```